# OpenSSL generates non-deterministic signature on CSR using P-256 or P-384 key, but not RSA key?

Tags: openssl, rsa, elliptic-curve, csr, libssl

When I use `openssl`'s command line to generate an RSA-2048 keypair, and then construct two Certificate Signing Requests (CSRs) for identical domain names using identical private keys, I get identical output.

```
$ openssl genrsa -f4 -out rsa.key | head -1
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key rsa.key -out rsa1.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key rsa.key -out rsa2.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
$ diff rsa1.csr rsa2.csr
```

But, when I generate an elliptic curve (P-256) keypair, and make two CSRs for identical domain names using identical private keys, I get two *different* outputs!

```
$ openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out p256.key
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key p256.key -out ec1.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key p256.key -out ec2.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
$ diff -U999 ec1.csr ec2.csr 
--- ec1.csr 2019-08-14 12:20:55.000000000 -0400
+++ ec2.csr 2019-08-14 12:20:59.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-MIHRMHgCAQAwFjEUMBIGA1UEAwwLZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggq
+MIHPMHgCAQAwFjEUMBIGA1UEAwwLZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggq
 hkjOPQMBBwNCAASKkrbzoJCjHgvI95U1ZYPG5AQUtN+ImrutI2KNAne/BvktGaHW
-ep2CEc5bliuYzxeC68cUG0MBmDrLZbRwaMS7oAAwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDSQAwRgIh
-AO1VziY7sHIKNFvCQnm+g7fguFSPoopHw+Jh3CKpjTKYAiEAmvlilKQkiN134T07
-LCDWfF/IlGeWv6nv1VhgsD3SEBU=
+ep2CEc5bliuYzxeC68cUG0MBmDrLZbRwaMS7oAAwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDRwAwRAIg
+AxHKjgwyXbeMqWK8XF/F6KztweW/tpY1U55pXyHeKgECID9jgdAQp7FetjbRGY7A
+GY0Y37x8XY5O3o5rEZSnsA1C
 -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

It's not a one-time thing. I generate 1000 CSRs using this P-256 key, I get 1000 different outputs. I generate 1000 CSRs using this RSA-2048 key, I get 1000 identical outputs.

```
$ for i in `seq 1 1000`; do openssl req -new -sha256 -key p256.key -out ec$i.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"; done
real    0m8.147s
user    0m5.972s
sys     0m1.810s
$ md5sum ec*.csr | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq | wc -l
1000

$ time for i in `seq 1 1000`; do openssl req -new -sha256 -key rsa.key -out rsa$i.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"; done
real    0m43.940s
user    0m41.386s
sys     0m2.049s
$ md5sum rsa*.csr | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq | wc -l
1
```

What on earth is going on here? Is there any way to force OpenSSL to generate reproducible output? Is there any reason I wouldn't want OpenSSL to generate reproducible output?

Is there any reason I *would* want OpenSSL to generate reproducible output when using RSA keys, but *not* when using EC keys?

---

I should add that I used https://certlogik.com/decoder/ to look at the CSRs being generated, and they look exactly the same *except* for the `BIT STRING` at the end, which I assume is supposed to be the SHA-256 signature?

I also see the same nondeterminism happening with P-384 keys:

```
$ openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -noout -out p384.key
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key p384.key -out ec1.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
$ openssl req -new -sha256 -key p384.key -out ec2.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
$ cmp ec1.csr ec2.csr 
ec1.csr ec2.csr differ: char 275, line 5
```

Comment: Ah, I found https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/851/can-ecdsa-signatures-be-safely-made-deterministic implying that non-determinism is an intentional feature of anything-signed-by-an-EC-key, which is really too bad. This question *might* just boil down to a duplicate of that one. But I don't understand well enough to say that it definitely is a duplicate.

Comment: RSA PKCS#1(v1.5) signatures are deterministic. RSA PSS signatures are not (random data is injected), and ECDSA (and DSA) are always non-deterministic (modulo the deterministic DSA RFC). Just the nature of the algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard ECDSA signatures are non-deterministic in nature. This is a fundamental characteristic of the algorithm. RSA signatures on the other hand are deterministic. So this is the reason that you see the difference between these types of keys.

There *is* an RFC which describes a process for generating deterministic ECDSA signatures (see [RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979)). However OpenSSL does not currently support it. There is an open pull request adding that capability [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/9223).